# Format numbers in pandas as currency in thousands or millions

Tags: python, pandas, numbers, format, currency

I have a dataframe: pd.DataFrame({"Amount":[19000000, 9873200, 823449242]}), and I need to convert the numbers into currency ($) in millions. i.e. $19.00MM, $9.88MM, and $823.45MM.

Does anyone know a quick way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can just do `df['($) millions'] = '$' + (df['Amount'].astype(float)/1000000).astype(str) + 'MM'`

Answer (score 18):

I think the following should work:

```
df['($) millions'] = '$' + (df['Amount'].astype(float)/1000000).astype(str) + 'MM'

In [3]:
df['($) millions'] = '$' + (df['Amount'].astype(float)/1000000).astype(str) + 'MM'
df

Out[3]:
      Amount   ($) millions
0   19000000        $19.0MM
1    9873200      $9.8732MM
2  823449242  $823.449242MM
```

if needed you can also `round`:

```
In [5]:
df['($) millions'] = '$' + (df['Amount'].astype(float)/1000000).round(2).astype(str) + 'MM'
df

Out[5]:
      Amount ($) millions
0   19000000      $19.0MM
1    9873200      $9.87MM
2  823449242    $823.45MM
```

Another method is to apply a `format` on each value using `apply`:

```
In [15]:
df['($) millions'] = (df['Amount']/1000000).apply(lambda x: '${:,.2f}MM'.format(x))
df

Out[15]:
      Amount ($) millions
0   19000000     $19.00MM
1    9873200      $9.87MM
2  823449242    $823.45MM
```

However, I expect the first method to scale better for large datasets, although sometimes list comprehensions are faster when it comes to strings

Here is the list comprehension method:

```
In [17]:
df['($) millions'] = ['${:,.2f}MM'.format(x) for x in df['Amount']/1000000]
df

Out[17]:
      Amount ($) millions
0   19000000     $19.00MM
1    9873200      $9.87MM
2  823449242    $823.45MM
```

Comment: I like this answer more!:)

Comment: I like the quick solution with the option to round number, thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: @EdChum How can I do more options like thousands, billions and so on?

Answer (score 4):

This simply divides the values - it does not add the `$` sign etc. (it's only a matter of changing the lambda function), but Amount is still dtype `float` so you can treat it as numbers.

```
 In [41]: df = pd.DataFrame({"Amount":[19000000, 9873200, 823449242]})

In [42]: df['MillionsAsFloat'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Amount'] / 1000000, axis=1
    ...: )

In [43]: df['MillionsAsString'] = df.apply(lambda row: '$' + str(round(row['Amount'] 
    ...: / 1000000,2)) + 'MM', axis=1)

In [44]: df
Out[44]: 
      Amount  MillionsAsFloat MillionsAsString
0   19000000        19.000000          $19.0MM
1    9873200         9.873200          $9.87MM
2  823449242       823.449242        $823.45MM
```

Comment: I think your solution not only changes the way we visualize the numbers and it empowers us to do calculations on the numbers. Brilliant!!!

Comment: Consider accepting the answer, so to show, this Q is resolved.:)

Comment: @quapka How can I do more options like thousands, billions and so on?

Comment: @TonyBrand you just have to specify the divisor in `row['Amount'] / <divisor>` accordingly.