# Convert values to currency with millions and thousands

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, type-conversion

I have a dataframe with a column of values in the *millions* **AND** *thousands*:

```
pd.DataFrame({"Market Value":[25500000, 500000, 1200000, 250000]})
```

I need to convert the numbers into currency (€) in millions AND thousands. i.e. €25.5M, €500k, €1.2M, €250k

This [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41271673/format-numbers-in-a-python-pandas-dataframe-as-currency-in-thousands-or-millions) I have gotten the code to do this conversion but only for columns with values in the millions, not for columns with values in the millions and thousands:

```
df['Market Value (€)'] = '€' + (df['Market value'].astype(float)/1000000).round(2).astype(str) + 'M'
```

Is there a way to adjust this code to also convert values in the hundreds of thousands (i.e. 250000 to €250k)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the desired output.

```
df['Market Value (€)']=np.select(condlist=[(df['Market Value']/1000)>1000],choicelist=['€'+(df['Market Value'].astype(float)/1000000).round(2).astype(str) + 'M'],default='€'+(df['Market Value'].astype(float)/1000).round(2).astype(str) + 'K')
```

Output:

[image]